# Can we generalize the gradient computation for Deep Neural Network for more than 2 hidden layers?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107574/gradients-of-sum-i-1n-w-3-gw-2-fw-1-x-i-y-i-22-w-r-t-w-1), thanks to greg, a solution for the gradient computations for the 2 hidden layers (or 3 layers in total per se) is presented. Now, if we want to generalize for the $L$ layers, then this becomes formidable at least to me.

How to obtain the gradient of 
\begin{align}
L(W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_L) := \sum_{i=1}^N \|W_L \ g(W_{L-1} \cdots f(W_{1} x_i) ) - y_i \|_2^2 \ ,
\end{align}
with respect to $W_{\ell}$ for all $\ell \in [1,\ldots,L]$?

I would highly appreciate your inputs/suggestions.

Comment: Are you aware of backprop?  Are you asking for something more than that?

Comment: When I look at the backproapagation, then it seems they do a lot of index based gradient computations. In the previous post, the answer was amazingly done.

Comment: Here's [something](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2974250/357854) with a fairly deep back-prop chain.