# Gradients of Deep Neural Network With Batch Normalization

Tags: matrix-calculus, neural-networks

How to obtain the gradients of such a complicated Deep network with batch normalization (preferably in matrix/vector notation)
\begin{align}
L\left(\left\{W_\ell, \gamma_\ell, \beta_\ell\right\}_{\ell=1}^3\right) := \sum_{i=1}^N \| g_3 \left(W_3 \ f_2 \left( g_2 \left(W_2 \ f_1 \left(g_1\left(W_1 x_i \right)\right) \right) \right) \right) - y_i  \|_2^2  ,
\end{align}
with respect to $\left\{W_\ell, \gamma_\ell, \beta_\ell\right\}_{\ell=1}^3$, where $g_\ell$ is parameterized by $\gamma_\ell$ and $\beta_\ell$?

The definition of $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $W_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $W_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times m}$, $W_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times p}$, and  $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^q$, and $f_\ell(z) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-z)}$.

And, 
$$\eqalign{
g_\ell(z; \gamma_\ell, \beta_\ell) &= \gamma_\ell \frac{\left( z- \mu(z) \right)}{\left( \sigma(z) + \epsilon \right)^{1/2}} + \beta_\ell\cr
\mu(z) &= \alpha \ 1^Tz \cr
\sigma(z) &= \alpha \sum_{k=1}^m \left( z[k] - \mu(z) \right)^2 \equiv \alpha 1^T \left[ \left( z-  \mu(z) \right) \odot \left(z -  \mu(z) \right) \right]\cr
}$$ where $1^T$ is a row vector with all ones, $\odot$ is an element-wise multiplication, and $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ are known scalars.

---

Note:

The gradients of the cost function **without** $g_i(\cdot)$, **batch normalization**, is given in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107574/gradients-of-sum-i-1n-w-3-gw-2-fw-1-x-i-y-i-22-w-r-t-w-1). But how to address it with complicated batch normalization.

---

Thank you so much in advance for your help